# Mathematica, maximize element extraction from list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

I think this is a simple question for mathematica experts.
How can I maximize the extracted value from a list given a index that has to respect some constrains?

For example:

```
S = {4,2,3,5}

Maximize[{Extract[S,x], x<= 3, x>=1},{x}]
```

I would like 4 is returned instead of this error:

```
Extract::psl: "Position specification x in Extract[{4,2,3,5},x] is not an integer or a list of integers."
```

Does someone know like solve this?

Thanks a lot.

---

Thanks a lot!! The last approach shown is what I was looking for but applied to my  real problem does not work.

I have the following problem:

I have to maximize the satisfaction of an employee with respect to a certain shift in an certain day of a month.
I have the matrix satisfaction (Employees,shifts) and is something like this:

```
S= {{4,3,5,2},{3,4,5,1}}
```

Each element represents the satisfaction of an employee with respect to a certain shift so employee 1 has satisfaction 4 with respect shift 1.

My model has to choose the right shift for all month days in order to maximize the employee satisfaction by respecting certain constraints.

My greatest problem is relate satisfaction matrix with chosen shift.
I am not able to use in method NMaximize a function that takes the chosen shifts and employee and returns the satisfaction and so doing a summation over all month days.
I need to maximize something like this:

```
Summation(from j=1 to j=31) getSatisfaction[1,chosenShift for that day)
```

Do you know how can I write this in mathematica?
I am struggling to this problem for several days but I am not able to solve this problem.
I need the input to relate chosen shift with satisfaction matrix.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please review my answer and tell me if it solves your problem, or if you seek something else.

Comment: @user: This site is made to give answers to single questions, [follow-up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19457/156389) questions don't really fit the model. This is not a forum. Also, can you please use code blocks for your code - to get help, press the question mark when you're editing your question. Finally, it's a bit rude to post the same question in [multiple locations](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=569736).

Comment: @user1114020 This is a confusing question. You say almost nothing about the nature of the constraints, or even what the matrix represents. Are there four shifts? Is each row to indicate a different employee? How many employees are there? How many are needed per shift? Are they interchangeable (at least for ones with comparable tasks)? If you provide a realistic description of the problem you will be more likely to get a reasonable response. Also, if I am not mistaken, the methods required will not be simple (looks like integer or constraint satisfaction programming might be needed).

Comment: @Daniel I have not inserted more details in order to not complicate too much my question.I'd like know how you may write my objective function and related satisfaction matrix in Mathematica. My problem is traslate it in Mathematica. I'm using goal programming.However here all request details: 1) the shifts are 19 but to simplify consider them 4. 2)yes each row matrix indicate a different employee (should be 20 but for simplify take in account only 2. 3) Depend on the week day of that month.

Comment: @Simon I really sorry for my mistakes. In the next post I will do like you told me.

Comment: @user1114020 my suggestion is this. Provide some input that would be "real life". Also show what result you would hope to obtain from that input. That might help considerably for readers like myself who have familiarity with Mathematica capabilities but are having trouble understanding the nature of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to find the value of `x` then I suggest you merely extract the acceptable range of the list and then find the `Max` of that:

```
s = {4,2,3,5};

s[[1 ;; 3]] // Max
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

If you have particularly hairy constraints then you may need something like Pick:

```
list = {5, 7, 1, 9, 3, 6, 2, 8, 4};

Pick[list, Range@Length@list, x_ /; x <= 7 && x >= 3 && Mod[7, x] == 1]
```

> ```
> {1, 6}
> ```

You can then use `Max` on the returned list.

---

For completeness, if you need the value of `x` or other details from the process, here is an approach:

```
list = {6, 5, 7, 3, 4, 2, 1, 8, 9};

pos = Cases[Range@Length@list, x_ /; x <= 7 && x >= 3 && Mod[7, x] == 1]

values = Part[list, pos]

maxpos = Part[pos, Ordering[values, -1]]
```

> ```
> {3, 6}
>
> {7, 2}
>
> {3}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Answering your updated question:

If you have:

```
shifts = {{4, 3, 5, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 1}, {4, 3, 5, 2}}
```

Then

```
(Tally /@ Transpose@shifts)[[All, 1, 1]]
```

gives you:

```
{4, 3, 5, 2}
```

Which i a list with the preferred shift for each employee.